# how do I display all unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

> this code

so this is an update on my application and I want an unchecked checkbox to appear, not just those that are checked

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sekolah_jurusan INNER JOIN jurusan ON jurusan.id_jurusan = sekolah_jurusan.id_jurusan WHERE id_sekolah = " . $sekolah['id_sekolah'];
    $jurusan = mysqli_query( $db, $query );
    foreach( $jurusan as $jur ) {
?>
    <input checked type="checkbox" id="" value="<?php echo $jur['id_jurusan'];  ?>" style="position: static;left: 0;opacity: 1;" name="jur[]"><?php echo $jur['nama_jurusan'];?>
    <br>

<?php  }?>
```

Comment: `not just those that are checked`-> how's you gonna decide that?

Comment: My question is how's you gonna decide that some check-boxes need to be check and some or not? Is there any field available in table to do so? Or do you have a value which you want to compare with all table records coming through query and based on that apply check or uncheck attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have a list of all items $allItems

  - Have a list of active items for the condition $activeItems
  - Loop then print
  - Add checked only when the printed element is in the active array.

> $allItems = array('1' => 'One', '2' => 'Two', '3' => 'Three', '4' => 'Four'); 
>   $activeItems = array('1','4');
>   foreach ($allItems as $jurID => $jur ) {
>       <input type="checkbox" <?php echo (in_array($jurID, $activeItems))?'checked':'';?> value="<?php echo $jurID ; ?>"name="jur[]">
>   <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Remove checked attribute from your code , it marks you chechbox as checked
also why are you putting value in input with type chechbox ,you should toggle checked attribute only

Comment: its of no use thats it i think